Github REST API - Retrieve Pull Request comments under "Conversation" section
I want to retrieve the comments that are added into a Pull Request under the tab "Conversation" through Github API.
I can already retrieve those directly inserted into the code under the tab "Files changed", however (through GET .../pulls/{pullRequestId}/comments), however, I cannot retrieve those added in the "Conversation" section. I have tried with GET .../issues/{pullRequestId}/comments, GET .../pulls)

I believe the endpoint you're looking for is:
GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues/{pull_request_id}/comments. It's a small change from the endpoint to get the comments on specific lines of code: /issues instead of /pulls.

Exactly ! In fact I tried this endpoint, but I did not see that the comment was indeed returned. I missed it because it was returned as another URL to call (.../issues/comment/{some_id}), instead of directly providing the content of this comment (like the textual content of the comment). Thanks a lot !
